# How to user MongoID near query with or condition

Tags: mongodb, geospatial

As per MongoID [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/#or-and-geospatial-queries), you can not use or with near queries. What can be the best alternative if you want to have an or condition with geo near query?
e.g. If I want to select all posts in a particular radius or posted by my friends?

**Update**

I have a collection that contains coordinates array like this

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a1b08977ab79403d100000e"),
    "coordinates" : [ 
        103.8632025, 
        1.3079616
     ],
    "user_id" : ObjectId("5a0dc29a7ab7946a63000005"),
}
```

If I perform near query i.e.

```
db.getCollection('COLLECTION_NAME').find({"coordinates":{"$nearSphere":[103.863325, 1.308015], "$maxDistance":0.012630230737833089}})
```

it works perfectly fine, but if I want to find all those records that are either created by this user or exists somewhere in around coordinates, I tried to concatenate both queries using $or

```
db.getCollection('COLLECTION_NAME').find({"$or": [{"coordinates":{"$nearSphere":[103.863325, 1.308015], "$maxDistance":0.012630230737833089}},{'user_id': ObjectId("5a0dc29a7ab7946a63000005")}] })
```

It responds with an error

```
Error: error: {
  "waitedMS" : NumberLong(0),
  "ok" : 0,
  "errmsg" : "geoNear must be top-level expr",
  "code" : 2
}
```

any workaround that you think I can use? Thanks

Comment: Need a more detailed explanation here. What is the query, and what have you tried? What's your expected result?

Comment: @KevinAdistambha updated

Comment: Currently, geo queries are special type of queries, and is not comparable to (and not combinable with) non-geo queries. If you need to do a query of `X near some location OR user is Y`, then you would have to do it with two queries and combine the results manually. The error message you're seeing is because you're trying to combine a "special" query and a "non-special" one.

Comment: Yeah, their documentation clearly said you cant, the manual stuff is already in my mind was wondering if someone found any other way around.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately as of MongoDB 3.4.10, there is no workaround for the query you posted, since geo queries are considered "special" queries and is treated differently vs. other queries. Currently, to achieve what you require, it has to be done manually by creating two queries and combining them in the application.

Having said that, there is a request for this feature: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-13974. Please upvote/comment on the ticket describing your use case and why this feature is important to you.